# NullPointerException: 'void android.widget.Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, android-switch

I am trying to reference my switch in my toolbar, but I get null pointer exception. I am guessing that I am referencing it wrong. I have experimented quite a lot and could not figure out what is actually wrong.

This is my switch layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Rearrage"
    android:checked="false"/>
```

This is my menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <item android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
      android:title="Rearrage"
      android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Main activity code:

```
private Switch reArrangeSwitch;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    reArrangeSwitch = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
    reArrangeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(switchListener);
...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.mySwitch);
    item.setActionView(R.layout.switch_layout);
    return true;
}
```

my switch listener:

```
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener switchListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Switch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

exception trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{koemdzhiev.com.quickshoppinglist/koemdzhiev.com.quickshoppinglist.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at koemdzhiev.com.quickshoppinglist.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:125)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activ
```

My main activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myMainRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar">
</include>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
    />

<TextView android:id="@+id/list_empty"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="No Shopping Items yet"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:id="@+id/myAdContainer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <com.software.shell.fab.ActionButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonFloat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        fab:show_animation="@anim/fab_roll_from_down"
        fab:hide_animation="@anim/fab_roll_to_down"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add the exception trace? It usually states a line on where the exception occurs.

Comment: The menu is already inflated with the action layout containing the switch. It's not in the activity layout. Use [`MenuItemCompat.getActionView(MenuItem)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#getActionView(android.view.MenuItem)) to retrieve it.

Comment: No the exact same excettion: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: I am using AppCompatActivity should I use SwitchCompat as well ?

Comment: Even I'm also having the same exception. @GeorgiKoemdzhiev